How to make a basic oval shape?
I need a basic oval shape to start and am having a hard time working out how to make an oval in Blender. Any ideas or tips?

Make a circle, select all (A), and scale (S) on X or Y.

Thank you! I now have a 2 dimensional oval shape how can I make it 3 dimensional?

Do the same with a sphere?

You can just create a circle primitive ⇧ Shift + A Add > Mesh > Circle and then scale it in either X direction ⇧ Shift + S or Y direction ⇧ Shift + Y you should have an oval.

Thank you! I followed this and now have a 2 dimensional oval shape how can I make it 3 dimensional?

You can  create a Torus instead SHIFT + A (Mesh > Torus) and scale as previous
